# Unable to add yii extension to my project?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

is their any *common method* to **add extension to my yii project**?
how can i add extension to my yii please explain the **steps**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Application Configuration**" plays important role when installing extensions. By default this configuration will be in a php file (i.e protected/config/main.php )

*Yii is a framework, not an application*  ... so you need to edit the php code yourself.

1) some people develops extensions as Yii components where you need to add these extensions into "**components**"  configuration.

2) Some people develops extensions as Yii modules, you need to add these modules into "**modules**"  configuration.

3) Some people develops **behaviors**, where you need to edit your Controller or model classes to add these behaviors.

there are many other types of extensions as well... you need to follow the guidelines provided by extension developer.

Comment: can u explain **extensions as Yii modules** and **extensions as Yii behavior**

Comment: yes sure, here is examples ...  1) extension as a module: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/sforum   2) as a behavior: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/audittrail2